# Simple Ruby Include Extend Example

Tags: ruby, include, extend

I think I'm missing something basic in understanding `include`,`extend`, etc. in classes. I have a class `OauthFigshare` that uses calls to the `OAuth` gem in it's single method `initialize`. I would like objects of this class to get access to the all the methods of `OAuth` so I get do things like `object.get`, after I've initialized it.

What would accomplish this, and could you explain the logic in your choice?

Full class included:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'oauth'

class OauthFigshare
    def initialize (consumerkey, consumersecret, accesstoken, accesstokensecret)
        @consumerkey = consumerkey
        @consumersecret = consumersecret
        @accesstoken = accesstoken
        @accesstokensecret = accesstokensecret
        @apiurl = "http://api.figshare.com"

        @consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(@consumerkey,@consumersecret,{:site=> @apiurl})
        @token = { :oauth_token => @accesstoken,:oauth_token_secret => @accesstokensecret}

        @client = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(@consumer, @token)
    end
end
```

Comment: why don't just derive from the `OAuth::Consumer` class? Like `class OauthFigshare < OAuth::Consumer`

Comment: I was thinking about that, but can I derive from the entire OAuth superclass, so I don't have to pick between `Consumer` and `AccessToken`?

Comment: `Consumer` doesn't have a superclass. And `AccessToken` derives from `ConsumerToken`. And think about it, if you could derive from a super class, then you won't have the functionality from `Consumer` and `AccessToken`!

Comment: Thanks! I think I actually need to derive from `AccessToken`, since this is whats actually used to to do html requests.